# MYSQL: I have two tables. I want to show data from table 1 and table 2 using FK in table 1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data from two tables. Table 1 is called Location and Table 2 is called Restaurant. Location has a field called **RestaurantID** (FK) which is the primary key in **Restaurant**. I want to show the value of column **"Location"** from table **Location** and the **"RestaurantID"**(PK in Restaurant and FK in Location) as well as "**Name**" value from **Table Restaurant**. I have attached MySQL table below.

[image: Table: Location]

[image: Table: Restaurant]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT l.location, l.restaurantid, r.name
FROM   location l
JOIN   restaurant r ON l.restaurantid = r.restaurantid
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for the noob question!